# IPSEC is Creating Multiple SAD's at rekeying in phase2

Tags: linux, ipsec

I am trying to create a tunnel between two peers with ipsec.while establishing the tunnel at first time, the number of sad(inbound & outbound) entries are as per number of peers. Once after reaching to soft limit of ipsec timer it is starting the re-negotiation to create new sad's, but it is not creating entries as per number of peers, it is negotiating & creating multiple sad entries until the timer reaches to Hard limit.

```
Example:-
#setkey -D | grep diff
diff:65       Hard:1000     soft:800
```

In between Soft to Hard limit, it is negotiating & creating multiple sad entries, sometimes my data is also not transferring from my site to peer site but timers are in active.

For this i have checked with versions from ipsec-tools-0.7.2 to ipsec-tools-0.8.2, i have checked all versions in between them & i am using linux kernel 2.6.11.

can any one tell me, what is the limit or how many it has to create while rekeying, otherwise why this many sad entires are being created.